# Is it possible to have OpenComputers get information from blocks from other mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods, minecraft-computercraft

I'm playing skyfactory 3 with OpenComputers 1.6.2.7 installed. I'm used to playing with computercraft where you could read information from blocks fron other mods and use them in your program (for example read rf/t output of a big reactors reactor). I'm trying to accomplish the same thing but with the OpnComputers mod (which is installed in skyblock 3 by default).

I'd like to setup the following:

- on demand crafting with the Refined Storage mod (the crafting is already setup I just want to be able to trigger it from a computer)
- See basic power consumption of an EnderIO compositor bank.
- See amount of liquid inside a Tinkers' Construct Casting Basin
- Check quantity of given item inside Refined Storage system.

I've no problem with writing the code to do this, however I don't know what blocks I need to interact with other mods or if it's even possible...

How would I go about doing this? again, I'm only looking for the hardware setup required (I already have setup a basic (tier 1) computer with screen, disk drive and keyboard)

Comment: What did you try so far? Does the computer just read NBT data? If yes, those tasks all seem pretty doable.

Comment: I've tried to see if a computer can check this information directly but it doesn't seem to be working... I probably need another block for that...

Comment: What did you try so far? And how does the computer work then?

Comment: I added an adapter to the blocks I want to interact with but I've not figured out how to use it yet